# Voronoi diagram algorithm with non-euclidean metric

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Do you know any easy to implement algorithm for constructing a Voronoi diagram from a given set of points on a surface, using some different metric (taxicab, for instance)?
It can be some modification of Fortune's algorithm.

Comment: See also [Voronoi diagram with different metric functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68777/voronoi-diagram-with-different-metric-functions) over on math.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the metric and your sites. There is a framework called **abstract Voronoi diagram** that allows you to compute Voronoi diagrams for *well-behaved* instances. In order to define what *well-behaved* means you have to give certain guarantees for the bisecting curves defined by your sites and your metric (for example two such curves intersect only in a finite number of points). The exact requirements might differ slightly depending on the paper you read.

If your problem is a abstract Voronoi diagram, then you can compute it with (a variant) of the *randomized incremental construction* due to Clarkson and Shor - see for example [here](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/RandomizedIncrementalAbstractVD.pdf). Then everything boils down to computations with the bisecting curves.

Note that there is quite some literature about these Voronoi diagrams and also recent progress has been made. I would advice you to go through this.